# Vertical menu/navigation bar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I was wondering how to accomplish the menu in the image below? Is it using a `LinearLayout` or is it using `RadioButtons`? Which would be the best solution? Could you also provide an example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for this type of iamge is to use LinearLayout and used 2 types of images for focus/selected tab. You have to set background color in Layout for same look and feel that you want.

Comment: Actually I think it's a radio button group with custom drawables :)

Comment: If we use radio button then you will not get view that you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `LinearLayout`(orientation: horizontal) with 6 `Button` s with custom nine patch backgrounds.